# How do I manually trigger a kubernates job (not a cron) in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

I have sample k8s job as soon as you do kubectl apply the job gets triggered and the pods are created . How to control the pod creation?

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi-with-timeout
spec:
  backoffLimit: 5
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "How to control the pod creation?" Control what exactly? Do you want to just run it? Create a new pod? Something else?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want just to run it with a manual trigger

Answer (score 4):

If you want to manually control the pod creation, you can achieve it through parallelism.

Documentation says:

> The requested parallelism (.spec.parallelism) can be set to any non-negative value. If it is unspecified, it defaults to 1. If it is specified as 0, then the Job is effectively paused until it is increased.

You can set it to 0 while doing the `kubectl apply`. Configuration looks something like below

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi-with-timeout
spec:
  backoffLimit: 5
  parallelism: 0
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

You can set it to 1 whenever you decide to run.

Comment: wow this helped thanks . I think we can patch a job by kubectl patch job pi-with-timeout --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/parallelism", "value":1}]'

Answer (score 1):

The trigger is running kubectl apply. When you create the Job, it runs. You might be looking for a more fully featured background task system like Airflow or Argo.

Comment: Also Rundeck seems like a good choice for manual triggers with web gui

Answer (score 0):

You can use `suspend: true` and then when you're ready to start the Job, you just update `suspend` to `false`.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/12/introducing-suspended-jobs/