# On Demand Containers in Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, memory, containers

We have the scenario, that we want to deploy ~300 java-applications for a in-house use-case in a kubernetes cluster. A lot of them are just used 4 times a year - and the rest of the year they are just wasting RAM.

**To reduce the memory footprint** we're currently discussing the following options:

1. Using a kubernetes-"buildt-in" mechanism, which starts the container when a request will arrive. After a timeout of (f.e. 10 hours) the container will be suspended/hibernated.
2. Offloading the RAM to disc (for specific containers) is allowed too.
3. Starting the containers by a "Proxy-Webpage": First, the user have to login to a web-app, where he is searching for and selecting the desired application. OnDemand (perhaps by a kubectl command in background etc) the application will be started.

Does someone have this special use-case, too?
We're starting this roject right now. So other options are helpful too. Just Java as development language is fixed.

- Is there a built-in solution in kubernetes, to reduce the memory footprint?
- Is our option #3 really a "good" solution?

Comment: Do you have 300 different Java applications or is it just one replicated 300 times?

Comment: We have really 300 different Java applications(not yet, but soon). No need for redundance. Kubernetes is just a place where they "living". Today, these applications are implemented in a visual programming language and stored as binaries on a network storage. This must be transformed into a modern way.

Comment: You could try to provide `Job`s and (mis)use the `parallelism` in order to run the Pods. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089350/how-do-i-manually-trigger-a-kubernates-job-not-a-cron-in-k8s), for example.

Comment: I'm also searching for a solution to provision pods on demand (here: incoming HTTP-request). Did you find a working solution?

Comment: Not really. I was frustrated, because we had no progress in developing our it-environment. So I left the company. ;-)